# one engine (boost::mt19937) multiple distributions (quality of randoms)

Tags: c++

I'm using boost_1_31_0 and I'm trying to create beta-distribution randoms (I'm using the fact that beta(alpha, beta) = gamma(alpha) / (gamma(alpha) + gamma(beta)))
I'm creating 16 random numbers each time using this (see below): The problem is that the random generated didn't respect the Law of large numbers: for each distribution when I calculate the average of generated numbers, it is different from the mean of the distribution. Is the conclusion is that we can't use the same engine for a lot of distributions?
My code is below:

```
//this engine is created in the top of my code.
boost::mt19937 eng;

//MyVector.size() is equal to 8, this boucle is called 100 000 times

for (int i = 0; i<MyVector.size(); i++)
{
    MyObject seedPtr = MyVector[i];
alpha = m_map_alpha.find(seedPtr)->second ;
boost::gamma_distribution<> gamma_alpha(alpha);
boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937&,boost::gamma_distribution<>> generator_gamma_alpha(eng, gamma_alpha);
alpha_random = generator_gamma_alpha();
boost::gamma_distribution<> gamma_beta(beta);
boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937&, boost::gamma_distribution<>> generator_gamma_beta(eng, gamma_beta);
beta_random = generator_gamma_beta();   
random = alpha_random / (alpha_random + beta_random ) ;
pair<myObject, double> graine(seedPtr, random);
mapRandoms.insert(graine);
}
```

Comment: Boost 1.31.0? _Really_? 1.50.0 is the current release.

Comment: You are re-seeding the engine after each generated random number, I wouldn’t be surprised that its output doesn’t obey laws of the distribution (including the law of large numbers).

Comment: no, i create it once, in the top of my code, without re-seeding it, because i want to have the same random numbers each time.

Comment: I think that i will use boost::mt19937 to create uniform randoms and apply this algorithm to create gamma random :  (gamma(S, 1): if 0<S<1::  1.b=(exp(1) + S)/exp(1), 2.generate U1~U(0,1), and let P=b.U1, if P>1, go to step 4, otherwise, go to step 3, 3.Let Y = P^(1/S) and generate U2~U(0,1), if U2 =< exp(-Y) return X=Y, otherwise go back to step 2, 4.let Y= -ln((b-P)/S) and generate U2~U(0,1). if U2=< Y^(S-1) return X=Y, otherwise go back to step 2.    if S>1 .....)  Do you know gays what is the algorithm used to create gamma randoms using the distribution boost::gamma_distribution<> ?

Comment: You were in fact re-seeding the rng every iteration. When you create a variate_generator it makes a copy of the URNG, and in your loop it is copy the same RNG state every tine

Comment: I will be very surprised if you don't get a lot of identical numbers with the above code. Did you have a look of the actual number generated? I know normal people won't do that but it does not hurt to have a look

Comment: in fact i think that variate_generator doesn't make copies, because the engine is token by reference, so there will no copy. i toke a look at the generated numbers and they are differents.

Comment: Didn't see you specified the template argument as reference. Then I have no idea why it does not work. Perhaps try a newer version of boost. 1.31 is really ages old. I generated beta varites the same way you did though with newer random library.